# Authorization access in CloudBees Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have requirement where in a folder we have created some jobs and want to give build access to some of the jbos and rest want have read only access. Let me explain it below.

```
Folder –
    Folder1 –
        Job1
        Job2
    Folder2
        Job1
        Job2
```

Here, I gave access to “Folder”, so all jobs in Folder1, Folder2 have build access. And then, want to restrict job1 from Folder1 to have read only access to the group created on “Folder”.  Please guide me to achieve this.

And also, could some enlighten me, if the authorization feature can be programmed through “job DSL” Plugin.

Thanks

Comment: You should open a separate question for the Job DSL part.

Answer (score 0):

Short: Create a role for these users and grant in these folders access to the role.

The documentation will go much more in dept of it as I can provide you here. It also has various examples:

- http://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/rbac.html
- https://www.cloudbees.com/products/cloudbees-jenkins-platform/team-edition/features/role-based-access-control-plugin

What is *not* easily possible:

- all users have access to everything
- only a few folders are restricted

A workaround here is an ugly hack where you limit access to the folder. The big downside here: As soon as you have a new role this newly created role will have access to all folders (and also jobs). So use this with care.
Due of this it is much easier if you lock everything down and then grant only selected permissions to roles.